# PHP MongoDB Exclude _id from results

Tags: php, mongodb, mongoid

I want to exclude _id field from mongodb search results using PHP. 
If I use $param as second search parameter it works but _id obviously gets printed.
Here is my code:

```
$type['Tipo de objeto']=$_POST[type];
$param = $_POST[field];
$conn = new Mongo();
$db = $conn->selectDB('prov');
$results = $db->$table->find($type, $param);

print_r($param) // Array ( [0] => Título [1] => Descripción [2] => Actos [3] => Formato original [4] => Título [5] => Descripción )
```

If i use the following code _id gets printed too, don't know what I`m missing:

```
$results = $db->$table->find($type, array("_id : 0" , "Derechos : 1", "Actos : 0")); //Fields marked with 1 gets printed, fields marked with 0 doesn't, except for _id.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not sending correctly your projection (the thing you are trying to return, second parameter in find)

So instead of this

```
array(
  "_id : 0" , 
  "Derechos : 1",
  "Actos : 0"
)
```

which is totally wrong, you have to type

```
array(
  "_id" =>  0, 
  "Derechos" => 1
)
```

Comment: It was so simple... Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

If you've landed here and are using the updated MongoDB Library, you might want to look here: [MongoDBCollection-find](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-find/)

and you'll need to do something like this:

```
    $fields = array(

        'projection'=>array(
            '_id'=>0,
            'Derechos'=>1,
        )

    );
```